# I can't identify the quantifier

Tags: logic

For a simple question like

Let $x, y \in Z$. If $3 | x$ or $3 | y$ then $3 | x y$.

Is it alright to assume all $x$ and all $y$ exist in $Z$?

I am trying to negate the statement but since it does not say 'each' explicitly, I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, it should be "for all" in the statement.

Comment: Okay thanks. Quick follow up please, in that case, when I negate I have
(3 is not divisible by xy) AND ( 3 | y OR 3 | x y)

So isnt this always true because of the first part (before AND) since I can choose any x and y say 3 and 1 that are divisible by 3 ? @Timbuc

Comment: Read my hinted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P = \forall\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\left[\;\left(3\mid x\;\;\vee\;\;3\mid y\right)\longrightarrow 3\mid xy\;\right]$$

and from here

$$\neg P=\exists\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\neg\left[\;\left(3\mid x\;\;\vee\;\;3\mid y\right)\longrightarrow 3\mid xy\;\right]$$

You now may want to use

$$A\longrightarrow B\equiv \neg A\vee B$$

and also

$$\neg (A\vee B)\equiv \neg A\wedge \neg B$$

Comment: Okay, my order was (not B and not A) but my question is- if I can prove any one of the parts false, then the original statement is correct right?

Comment: If you meant to prove that in $\;\neg A\wedge\neg B\;$ any of these two parts is false then the answer is yes, as conjunction is true *only* if both its parts is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for being patient with a noob. Cool bio too! @timbuc